# if I create jquery ui dialog on the fly , is there any clean up beside calling dialog("close") in a single page app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

in  a single page web app, if I create jquery ui dialog on the fly like this:

```
 $("<div>hello</div>").dialog({ 
      buttons : { 
           "cancel" : function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close");
           } 
      } 
 });
```

Do I need to do any special clean up after each closing? Do I need to call dialog's "destroy"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `destroy` if you plan to completely re-create the dialog each time it's opened, as would happen it the code above is called more than once.

If the dialog only gets opened once, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Can I call it inside the "cancel" button handler function ? like this  $(this).dialog("destroy");  // I fear that this is still in use

Comment: @dan_l yes, I normall do `$(this).dialog('close').dialog('destroy')`